Show that $Y_t=B_t-tB_1$ and $X_t=B_t-(1-t)\int_{0}^{t}\frac{B_s}{(1-s)^2}ds$ have the same distribution
$(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a brownian motion.
I can't seem to find le covariance for $X_t$ and that's what I need to show they have the same distribution since both are gaussian.
Is there another way to find it?

You should mention that $Y_t$ and $X_t$ are both Brownian bridges.
Integration by parts
$$\tag1
d\left\{\frac{B_t}{1-t}\right\}=\frac{B_t\,dt}{(1-t)^2}+\frac{dB_t}{1-t}
$$
implies
$$\tag2
B_t=(1-t)\int_0^t\frac{B_s\,ds}{(1-s)^2}+(1-t)\int_0^t\frac{dB_s}{1-s}
$$
so that we see that $X_t$ is the Gaussian
$$\tag3
(1-t)\int_0^t\frac{dB_s}{1-s}\,.
$$
Further straightforward calculations show that it has the covariance function
$$\tag4
\operatorname{Cov}[X_t,X_s]=\min(t,s)-ts
$$
of the Brownian bridge.
